# How to reset delegate to original code

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates

given this delegate

```
public class XYZ
{
    public static Action<Profile> DoSomething = (profile) =>
    {
        //some default code here
        return;
    };
}
```

at some time in my main execution I override it with this:

```
XYZ.DoSomething = (currProfile) => 
{
    // some overriding code here
}
```

How do I set the code back to the original default code when I need to without duplicating code?

Comment: Create a method that you can call that assigns the default (i.e. original) to the property. You can invoke that method from the constructor to ensure initialization.

Comment: AFAIK you can't unless you save the original one in a different variable. Edit: okay Kenneth is right.

Comment: If this is a temporary swap you could also assign the original to a variable then assign it back.  Really depends on how you're using this though.

Comment: This isn't delegate specific, it's the same answer if the variable were an `int` or a `string`...

Comment: I can take the down votes, but with no explanation it's hard to correct the wrong. Any idea why?

Comment: I didn't vote, but my guess would be that its similar to things you can find (ie David's comment); or just people that think its a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you Bradley. I guess we have our own sneaky little Trumps here too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a good reason to never use public fields...

Once you set it; its gone. You can hold onto the original value though:

```
var originalAction = XYZ.DoSomething;
XYZ.DoSomething = ...;
XYZ.DoSomething = originalAction;
```

Usually it is a bad idea to rely on client code to handle this however; so if I was writing it I would expose as a property like so:

```
public Action<X> DoSomethingOverride {get; set;}
public Action<X> DoSomething => doSomethingOverride ?? DefaultMethod;
private void DefaultMethod (X param)
{
}
```

There are a number of other ways to handle this, but all involve storing off the original method. All good ways to handle this will use a property to ensure that only the declaring class is actually setting the `DoSomething` method and that resetting to the default is possible.

Total aside; since this is `static` setting the action will affect *everything that uses this class*. This is asking for bugs later; don't do that.

Comment: agree on the static comment. Not an issue in this case though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe somthing like this?

```
public static Action<Profile> _doSomethingBase = (profile) =>
{
    //some default code here
    return;
};

public static Action<Profile> _doSomething = _doSomethingBase;

public static Action<Profile> DoSomething
{
    get => _doSomething;
    set => _doSomething = value;
}

public static void RevertDoSomething()
{
    DoSomething = _doSomethingBase;
}
```